# How to loop through a byte array in C programming and store in a string as Hexadecimal

Tags: c, arrays, hex, byte

How to loop through a byte array in C programming and store the hexadecimal output of each byte element in a string as Hexadecimal. I am using VS2005.

```
int main(int ArgC,char** ArgV)
{
    char*           string;
    char            stringSHA1[3];
    char*           stringSHA1Final = "";
    Sha1Context     sha1Context;
    SHA1_HASH       sha1Hash;
    uint16_t        i;

    string = "Hello World";//ArgV[1];

    Sha1Initialise( &sha1Context );
    Sha1Update( &sha1Context, string, (uint32_t)strlen(string) );
    Sha1Finalise( &sha1Context, &sha1Hash );

    stringSHA1Final = malloc(sizeof(sha1Hash)*2 + 1);

    for( i=0; i<sizeof(sha1Hash); i++ )
    {
        printf( "%2.2x", sha1Hash.bytes[i] );
        sprintf_s(stringSHA1, 5, "%s%02x", "0x", sha1Hash.bytes[i] );
        stringSHA1Final[i] = stringSHA1;
    }
    printf( stringSHA1Final );

    return 0;
}
```

I have trouble in concatenating the hexadecimal string into a single string and return.

Comment: What is yor exact question? why does your code fail? And normaly hashing libraries have functions to obtain the so called **digest** which is apparently what you want.

Comment: @iharob - the sprintf is able to write hexadecimal to command line, but I want to concatenate in the string and pass it back.

Comment: I don't think you understand `sprintf()` please read the manual for it or the standard specification.

Comment: @iharob - sprintf is fine. I want to concatenate the hexadecimal output to string and return it.

Comment: @iharob - I got to make it work 
for( i=0; i<sizeof(sha1Hash); i++ )
 {
  printf( "%2.2x", sha1Hash.bytes[i] );
  sprintf_s(stringSHA1, 3, "%02x", sha1Hash.bytes[i] );
  stringSHA1Final = concat(2, stringSHA1Final, stringSHA1);
}
return stringSHA1Final;

Comment: The answer I gave will have the same effect it's just more efficient and elegant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a pointer, like this

```
char *sha1final = stringSHA1Final;
for (i = 0 ; i < sizeof(sha1Hash) ; i++)
 {
    int count;
    count = snprintf(sha1final, 2, "%02x", sha1Hash.bytes[i]);
    if (count < 0)
        continue; /* You have to handle this, it's an error */
    sha1final += count;
 }
```

Comment: I am using VS2005, not sure if I can use snprintf though.

Comment: I recommend switching to a more developer like environment like Linux/gcc but there is an equivalent function I guess.